# Possible to create a Hyper-V VM with a unique IP address? What are my options?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v

I'm testing IP throttling on my site and want to spawn a VM that has a different IP address from the one on my local machine. This seems impossible but I want to ask the community - is the only way to achieve this by spawning a VM in the cloud, such as in Azure?

Comment: Huh? Why wouldn't this be possible?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Because he only has one externally-facing IP, I bet.  Either way, needs moar information.

Comment: @HopelessN00b - that's right.  What more can I tell you?  I'm running a bit blind here :/

Comment: The fact that your host is a VM really has nothing to do with getting valid IPs.  Not sure why it is tagged as such. If you want a public IP you must be connected to a network that has available public IPs.  How you do that is up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you need to use a VPN with your Hyper-V VM to tunnel your traffic to another IP address.  There are a lot of free VPN services available on the internet that you could easily attain for these testing purposes.  If the tests will run for a longer period of time, I'd suggest renting a VPS, you can get extremely cheap ones for about $60 a year.

Comment: Awesome!  I'll look into this.  Do you have any recommended services / reading?

Comment: It really depends on what you're looking for.  I've had great experiences with both ChicagoVPS (http://www.chicagovps.net/) and BudgetVM (https://www.budgetvm.com/).  These are NOT production worthy solutions, but from reading your post, it seemed that cost was more important than stability.  If stability is important you'd probably be better off with a dedicated box from Hivelocity (https://www.hivelocity.net/)